# Multiple Kendo UI Grid with dropdown editor templates edit issues in ASP.NET MVC razor page

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, editortemplates

I have two Kendo UI grids with drop down editor template columns in an ASP.NET MVC razor page.Both grids are having one row always and working fine with edit and update.

But when the user clicks one first grid edit and trying to click the second grid edit then the editor templates are not working for the second grid. it is showing the grid values within a textbox. Both grids are sharing same editor templates for the columns. No errors in the browser console.

I tried moving these grids in partial views and try to create different editor templates for each grid but always the result is the same.

The funny thing is that if you edit in the second grid first and then click the first grid edit it doesn't create any problem and shows all the dropdown values with editor templates. (first and second grid means from top to bottom)

both grids have different models but share the same class for the model.

I am giving the sample code here ..please help me ..already spent lot of time on this.

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModel.EmployeesViewModel

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CasualEmployees)
                  .Name("GridCasualEmployees")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(i => i.Frequency).Title("Frequency").EditorTemplateName("Frequency").ClientTemplate("#:Frequency#").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:Left; " }).Width(75);
                      columns.Bound(i => i.Quarter).Title("Quarter").EditorTemplateName("Quarter").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(Quarter,\"MMM yyyy\") #").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:left; " }).Width(75);
                      columns.Bound(i => i.EmpId).Hidden();
                      columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(175);
                  })
                  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                  .Editable((editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
                  .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                      .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                  .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                      .AllowUnsort(true)
                      .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .Batch(true)
                      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Id(s => s.EmpId);
                          model.Field(s => s.Frequency);
                          model.Field(s => s.Quarter);
                      })
                      .Create(update => update.Action("CreateEmployee", "Employee"))
                      .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmployee", "Employee"))
                      .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateEmployee", "Employee"))
                  )
                  )


    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.PermanentEmployees)
                  .Name("GridPermanentEmployees")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Bound(i => i.Frequency).Title("Frequency").EditorTemplateName("Frequency").ClientTemplate("#:Frequency#").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:Left; " }).Width(75);
                      columns.Bound(i => i.Quarter).Title("Quarter").EditorTemplateName("Quarter").ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(Quarter,\"MMM yyyy\") #").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:left; " }).Width(75);
                      columns.Bound(i => i.EmpId).Hidden();
                      columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(175);
                  })
                  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
                  .Editable((editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
                  .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                      .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                  .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                      .AllowUnsort(true)
                      .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                      .Ajax()
                      .Batch(true)
                      .ServerOperation(false)
                      .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Id(s => s.EmpId);
                          model.Field(s => s.Frequency);
                          model.Field(s => s.Quarter);
                      })
                      .Create(update => update.Action("CreateEmployee", "Employee"))
                      .Read(read => read.Action("ReadEmployee", "Employee"))
                      .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateEmployee", "Employee"))
                  )
                  )




 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i)
                    .Name("Quarter")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Quarters)
                    .OptionLabel("Select Quarter")
    )


        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i)
                        .Name("Frequency")
                        .DataValueField("Id")
                        .DataTextField("Name")
                        .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Frequencies)
                        .OptionLabel("Select Frequency")
        )

     public class EmployeesViewModel
        {
            public List<Employee> CasualEmployees{ get; set; }
            public List<Employee> PermanentEmployees{ get; set; } 
        }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You may be running into an issue where the DOM elements (dropdownlists, textboxes, etc.) that are the same are trying to use the same Id within the grids.  This would explain why the first grid works, but the second does not.  JavaScript is very particular about elements with the same Id in use and refuses to work how we envision it should work.  Unless it's a user requirement to be able to edit both grids at once, I would force the user to finish editing one grid before allowing edits of another (if using the same template with the same fields).

Comment: It is hard to convince the tester like this. I tried different templates, put each grid in different partial views, used different name of variables and the model object but the result is same.

Comment: If different names (for fields) were used and you still see nothing working in the 2nd grid, and the grids work "individually", then I think you might be hitting an issue from within the Kendo framework.  Their (Kendo) selector may be dependent on a class name that wraps around the editing area/template instead of id-specific based on the grid name (guessing).